# How can i remove arrow from ion-item in Ionic 4.7.1 (Only IOS)

Tags: ios, ionic4

I have the following:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.7.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/pds/Library/Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v11.6.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.5.0-next.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2 Build version 10E125
```

According to this documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#detail-arrows, in order to not display the arrows on IOS you need to set **detail property to false** but it's not working.

```
<ion-item (click)="abrirUsados()" routerLink="#">
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <img src="/assets/img/usados.png">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label>
            <h3 ion-text color="primary">Usados</h3>
            <p>Revisados y buen uso</p>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" slot="end" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
```

The `detail-icon="none"` works, but there it shows a blank space and the icon I added is not floating to right as it should.

[image: the icon is not floating to right as intended]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try `detail='false'`for removing and `detail='true'` for display in ion-item

if the above is not working try `mode='md'`

check this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#detail-arrows)

```
<ion-item (click)="abrirUsados()" routerLink="#" detail="false" mode='md'>

   <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
    <img src="/assets/img/usados.png">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-label>
     <h3 ion-text color="primary">Usados</h3>
     <p>Revisados y buen uso</p>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" slot="end" color="primary"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I have already tried detail="false", but it's not working, meanwhile detail-icon="none" works but there is an undesired white space i can't remove. The main problem is that i can't touch the css globally cause i have the android part too.

Comment: There is a lack of documentation in this framework.

Comment: try `mode='md'` and `detail='false'` as given in my answer

Comment: It's working! Thank you! Is there any possibility to put it as variable in /theme/variables.scss? That's cause i have a lot of items to edit...

Comment: create a separate question and will answer

Comment: Thanks it helped. 
But I am running Ionic react . so I had to do it like this 
<IonItem detail={false}>
Incase if anyone interested